# Git commit on .png seems to garble up the file

Tags: git

This is really weird, and I don't know what else to do.

`git commit` seems to garble up a png file, so that it is not displayable anymore. I had GPG signing on, and disabled it to prevent this from being a factor.

I uploaded the original and the garbled file; for your notice, the garbled file won't display in your browser.

Some vital stats:

```
# uname -a
Linux memphis-wsl 4.19.128-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 12:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# git --version
git version 2.25.1
```

Original:
[image: Original Picture]

After `git commit`:
[image: After git commit]

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question! It was our pre-commit hook which didn't exclude .png files. Sorry for the false alarm. Hope this will help somebody in the future!